# How to append behat results to one html file

Tags: behat

Scenario:

1) I run php bin/behat features/1.feature > result.html
2) I then run php bin/behat features/2.feature > result.html
3) I should see the results of both 1.feature and 2.feature in results.html

How can I get this done ? does behat have a option for appending ?

maybe php bin/behat features/1.feature --append > results.html ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use profiles in behat.yml and indicate which features to run per profile.
So instead of running behat several times, once for each .feature, you just run it once and obtain one html file instead of several.

Example: the following config has 2 profiles, one for login scenarios and one for booking scenarios. 
It also filters out scenarios tagged @wip.
It outputs data on the command line ('pretty') and in an html file ('html'):

```
#behat.yml

default:
    filters:
        tags: "~@wip"

    formatter:
        name: pretty,html
        parameters:
            output_path: null,behat_report.html

login:
    paths:
        features: features/login
        bootstrap: %behat.paths.features%/bootstrap

booking:
    paths:
        features: features/booking
        bootstrap: %behat.paths.features%/bootstrap
```

You can then run the profile you want:

```
behat --profile login
```

which will run all the .feature files inside the features/login/ directory